# DataTables paging buttons correctly rendered, but disabled (search, sorting and page size OK tho)

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have integrated DataTables into an ASP.NET site. Everything is working as expected, except the paging buttons.

The paging buttons are rendered but nothing happens when they are clicked. There is also no hover effect.

Changing page size works, and the paging buttons are re-rendered correctly for the new page size. I can't see any JS errors.

The DataTables version is 1.10.20 (no additional plugins). Also used are Bootstrap 4.3.1, jQuery 3.2.1 & jQuery SlimMenu.

To see the issue [click here](http://lneville.s18.dotnetsql.com/Data/Countries/List.html). This is a static HTML equivalent of a page rendered by ASP.NET ... I can't do anything about the table being in a form, the wierd IDs ... that is done by ASP.NET.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer courtesy of Allan at [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/58923).

The *pointer-events: none* in the following CSS was killing the click on those buttons:

```
a:not([href]) {
    color: #333;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

The paging buttons have no href attribute so are being targeted by that rule. *pointer-events: none* prevents all click, state and cursor options on the specified HTML element, i.e. the click and mouse-over.